# Simple bitmap rotation for arduino, c++

Tags: c++, bitmap, arduino, avr

I'm trying to achieve compromise for my app, but got no luck (or rather knowledge) so far.

I've got bitmap for black-white screen, it looks like this (I use arduino byte style, because it's more readable)

```
{
    B00111100, B01001000,
    B00100100, B01010000,
    B00111100, B01110000,
    B00100100, B01001000
}
```

It is array of bytes, each byte representing 8 next horizontal pixels.
Problem is that I have to use bitmap, where each byte represents 8 next vertical pixels, so it's like turning it this way

```
{
    B00000000,
    B00000000,
    B11110000,
    B10100000,
    B11110000,
    B00000000,

    B11110000,
    B00100000,
    B01100000,
    B10010000
}
```

I tried, but ended up completely without any idea how to do this.

Edit. I could be misunderstod, so I added brackets to code, It's more clear right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using plain C (gcc):

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef uint8_t byte;

void print_bin(byte x) {
    printf("B");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%s", (x >> (7-i)) % 2 ? "1" : "0");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void reverse(byte* in, byte* out, int width, int height) {
    int width_bytes = (width + 7) / 8;
    int height_bytes = (height + 7) / 8;
    // init *out. You can skip the next line if you are sure that *out is clear.
    memset (out, 0, width * height_bytes);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (in[(y * width_bytes + x / 8)] & (1 << (7 - x % 8))) {
                out[(x * height_bytes + y / 8)] |= (1 << (7 - y % 8));
            }
        }
    }
}

#define WIDTH  13
#define HEIGHT  4
#define IN_SIZE  (((WIDTH + 7) / 8) * HEIGHT)
#define OUT_SIZE (((HEIGHT + 7) / 8) * WIDTH)

int main() {
    byte in[IN_SIZE] = {
        0b00111100, 0b01001000,
        0b00100100, 0b01010000,
        0b00111100, 0b01110000,
        0b00100100, 0b01001000
    };

    byte* out = calloc(OUT_SIZE, 1);
    reverse (in, out, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    for (int i = 0; i < OUT_SIZE; i++) {
        print_bin(out[i]);
    }

}
```

And this is the result:

```
B00000000
B00000000
B11110000
B10100000
B10100000
B11110000
B00000000
B00000000
B00000000
B11110000
B00100000
B01100000
B10010000
```

If speed is an issue, you can do the following optimisation:

```c
void reverse(byte* in, byte* out, int width, int height) {
    int width_bytes = (width + 7) / 8;
    int height_bytes = (height + 7) / 8;
    // init *out. You can skip the next line if you are sure that *out is clear.
    memset (out, 0, width * height_bytes);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int t; // optimisation
            if ((x % 8) == 0) t = in[(y * width_bytes + x / 8)];
            if (t & (1 << (7 - x % 8))) {
                out[(x * height_bytes + y / 8)] |= (1 << (7 - y % 8));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I forget to mention, I'm sorry :<.

It is not two-dimensional array, but one dimensional, so It's a bit harder. It would be really easily to do it this way.

It's more like
`{B00111100, B01001000,
B00100100, B01010000,
B00111100, B01110000,
B00100100, B01001000}`

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out as soon as possible and tell how it works!

Comment: Oh, it's working but it won't do the trick for bitmaps wider than 8 pixels, right? That's the trickies part - there could be even 84x48 bitmap

Comment: Now it gets interesting. I just update the solution with a more universal one.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! Really, I owe you a beer. A whole lot of beer.